# Separately move label in a "multi-label" object situation using QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am using QGIS in order to show countries of the world with both their names and a number. I use rule-based labeling to place each one of them. The position of the countries' name is  predetermined in a specific attribute, so it is indicated in the corresponding rule's description. The position of the numbers is the countries' one but with an offset. (three millimeters below in my case).
So, I have something like this:

[image]

My problem comes when I want to move the number in green separately because I am not convinced by its current position. I use the option "Move the label or diagramm". But, when I move the green number, the country name in black is moved as well to give something like this:

[image]

Do you know a simple trick so that I can move the green number without moving the label in black? I have in mind "complicated" tricks such as create a new layer specifically for the numbers but it looks not simple...

Answer (score 0):

There is a new feature in QGIS 3.20 Odense (in Print Layouts). When using dynamic, or expression-based labels, users may now select the «Convert to Static Text» option which has been added to the dropdown menu next to «Insert/Edit Expression…», in the layout label properties widget. Now it is possible to convert dynamic labels to static ones and manually tweak the results when needed.
https://qgis.org/ru/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-convert-to-static-text-option

Comment: Thank you for this clarification!

Comment: @LéoMazel did it solve your problem?

Comment: Not immediately, I would prefer working with the "stable" version of QGIS (3.16) so I will look for another solution and keep yours in mind. I fear my problem is quite specific so it would require further detail (too much?) to really appreciate the problem... Anyway, thanks for asking and again for your help!